# In the command line prompt, how do I show the full home path instead of the tilde (~)?

Tags: command-line, ps1

In the terminal prompt, how do I get to see the full path of the home directory?

That is, from

```
root@pcname:~ #
```

to

```
root@pcname:/home/username #
```

Comment: FYI, the Ubuntu version does not make any difference.

Comment: O...IC.  For some reason I wanted to know, though.  Didn't fully realize the "~" was used as an abbreviation (The title of this question was different...the new title could also help others, though).  Thanks.

Comment: My actual question implied that there was a difference between the files shown under each...but if it is indeed an abbreviation I won't make any more trouble...(just making sure)...

Comment: Are you using bash? zsh?

Comment: @KasiyA,@chaos,@guntbert,@DavidFoerster,@Braiam: My original question was edited.  Did you put on hold that one, or the edited one?

Answer (score 4):

In your prompt (look for `PS1` in your `.bashrc`), use `$PWD` instead of `\w`.

For example, your `.bashrc` would contain:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

In both cases, change the second `\w` to `$PWD`:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]$PWD\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:$PWD\$ '
fi
```

According to `man bash`, `\w` is the abbreviated path:

```
\w     the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde (uses the value of the PROMPT_DIRTRI`M variable)
```